# $ionicScrollDelegate.resize() does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have section where i'm using ng-show and ng-class directives, i've got a function which open and close this seation and resize

HTML:

```
         <span class="main" id="actions">Actions</span>
            <button class="button-clear toggle-button" ng-click="resize()"><i ng-class="{'my-up-icon': actionHide, 'my-down-icon': !actionHide}"></i></button>
            <section ng-show="actionHide" class="hide-section">
                <div class="details-section">
                    <i class="icon my-posted-icon add-icon-details"></i>
                    <h2>Posted</h2>
                    <p>24.08.2015 16:35</p>
                </div>
                <div class="details-section">
                    <i class="icon my-update-icon update-icon-details"></i>
                    <h2>Updated</h2>
                    <p>24.08.2015 16:35</p>
                </div>
                <div class="details-section">
                    <i class="icon my-update-icon update-icon-details"></i>
                    <h2>Updated</h2>
                    <p>24.08.2015 16:35</p>
                </div>
                <div class="details-section">
                    <i class="icon my-remove-icon delete-icon-details"></i>
                    <h2>Deleted</h2>
                    <p>24.08.2015 16:35</p>
                </div>
            </section>
```

js:

```
$scope.resize = function() {
  $scope.actionHide = !$scope.actionHide;
  $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
}; // resize
```

when i'm click on button and opening this section, i still can't scroll down, why resize() does not work?

Answer (score 2):

For me just solved adding `overflow-scroll="true"` to ion-content.

Comment: Thank you most kindly - been racking my brains about this for a YEAR.

Answer (score 2):

Just add timeout to $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();

ex:

```
$timeout(function() 
{
$ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code I can't necessarily say exactly why it's not working except that you need to ensure two things:

1. [ion-content or ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/) directives are used as the delegate is responsible for controlling scrollViews created by those directives;
2. $ionicScrollDelegate is correctly injected into your controller

Usage

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <button ng-click="resize()">Resize!</button>
    <section ng-show="actionHide">
       ... content ...
    </section>
  </ion-content>
</body>

...

function MainCtrl($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
  $scope.resize = function() {
    $scope.actionHide = $scope.actionHide;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
  };
}
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/rickymarcon/pen/OyPgzm) for an example.